# Popping a query from django Q query?

Tags: python, django, django-q

I'm working with a query that looks like so:

```
    filters = Q(is_default = False)
    # Build the excludes and filters dynamically 
    if cut:
        filters = filters & Q(mailbagstats__num_letters2__gt = int(cut) )
```

Given the `filters` `Q` query, can I `pop` one of the queries?

I'd like to remove the `Q(mailbagstats__num_letters2__gt= int(cut) )` query from this Q query for a new filter down the line.

Normally, I use lists and `reduce` but this one is constructed via  `Q() & Q()` so I'm not sure how to modify it.

Thanks for any input you might have!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can `pop` them:

```
>>> filter = Q(a=True)
>>> filter = filter & Q(b=True)
>>> filter.children
[('a', True), ('b', True)]
>>> filter.children.pop()
('b', True)
>>> filter.children
[('a', True)]
```

Comment: Very nice! Thanks! I will write a function that takes a key and iterates through the list (`children` requires recursion too) and pops  them!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you work with lists and made the filter at the end?

```
filters = []
filters.append(Q(is_default = False))
# Build the excludes and filters dynamically 
if cut:
    filters.append(Q(mailbagstats__num_letters2__gt = int(cut)))

# I want to pop the last one
filters.pop()

# build the filter before making the query
# Note that this call will remove an element from the filters list
filters_for_query = reduce(lambda a, x: a & x, filters, filters.pop())

Model.objects.filter(filters_for_query)
```

Comment: The `children` attribute is a list

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was just proposing other solution. I like to handle lists. You're answer is better for this particular question. +1 ;)

Comment: No, it's okay. I wasn't saying my answer was better. Just pointing out  that there is no need for a new list since you already have one :)

Comment: And hey! I hope we can beat Argentina tonight! xD

Comment: I normally do lists, but in this case the code I'm working with uses the other syntax.

Comment: Haha, @César, It'll be hard for us. You've got a pretty strong team. And, yes, your answer is better. It goes straight to the point.